# Fill in the blank to win

Tags: pattern

Given the six, four digit numbers below, find me a seventh that matches the pattern.

```
2058
1724
1234
6245
5683
8756
????
```

Note that there are many possible answers, but if you find the pattern, it should be absolutely obvious if it's correct or not.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a variation of my puzzle? :P

Comment: @Joe - it was trying to solve yours that made me think of this one. :) ...No idea how close their solutions are though, as I couldn't crack yours.

Comment: By "many possible answers", do you mean "many correct answers"?

Comment: @Joe - many correct answers (but you only need to list one and I'll immediately know you understand the pattern).

Comment: Having seen JoeZ's solution and then looked again at the first 2 rows of his puzzle, I see how you came up with this! ;-) @JoeZ. I think your puzzle will inspire a **lot** of new ones as people come up with increasingly crazy ideas that don't actually work with yours.

Comment: @randal'thor If that happens, that's a great thing for this community! I look forward to solving all of them. :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the number pad on a phone:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
* 0 #
```

Now, consider the positions that each of the numbers fills.

```
. 2 .   1 2 .   1 2 3   . 2 .   . . 3   . . .
. 5 .   4 . .   4 . .   4 5 6   . 5 6   . 5 6
. 8 .   7 . .   . . .   . . .   . 8 .   7 8 .
  0       .       .       .       .       .
```

These are six of the seven pieces that appears in Tetris. The last remaining piece is the square, which can appear in four different positions:

```
1 2 .   . . .   . 2 3   . . .
4 5 .   4 5 .   . 5 6   . 5 6
. . .   7 8 .   . . .   . 8 9
  .       .       .       .
```

So any permutation of **1245**, **2356**, **4578**, or **5689** would be a correct answer.

Comment: Well done. Definitely one of the possible correct answers. :)

Comment: That was actually an interesting, frustrating puzzle. I loved the more-than-one-correct-answer twist, which actually made it *harder* to think about, if you can believe it.